# set maxlength in a textfield according to the size of the text

Tags: java, jsp, character, maxlength

how to set the maxlength in a textfield according to the size of the text?How to set the textfield size irrelated to the character?

When setting max length say for example my textfield size is 10. But when i type all 1's in the text field, text field is filled till its half. 
But when I try to set a UpperCase A, i.e. 10 A's then the textfield is filled and even overflows for that 10 chars.

How to set the textfield size irrelated to the character?

Comment: ...what? Are you talking about HTML, like `<input maxlength="10" />`?

Comment: yes, even in HTMLs, if i put maxlength=10 and width=10, then for each character the endpoint differs. For 1 the end point is at the half of the textfield, for A the endpoint of 10th charcter is at the end of the textfield.

Comment: So you want an `input` field which starts out small and then auto-increase as characters are entered?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your tags correctly. I was thinking you meant Swing. Once I realized that, I deleted my post. But I'm assuming the same principle applies. Different fonts have different "point" sizes and thus take up differing amounts of space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should choose a monospaced font.

E.g.

```html
<input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" style="font-family: monospace;">
```

*(note: above is just an example; the normal practice is to define CSS in its own `.css` file and use `class` attribute to refer it)*

Result:

[image]

The `font-family: monospace` will choose the browser's default monospaced font. But there are more, such as `Lucida Console`, `Courier New`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean something like this? This will auto-scale the input field to the width of what you put in.

```
<input style="display:inline-block; width:10px; overflow:visible;" type="text" maxlength="10" />
```

Or you can use this to make every character the same width.

```
<input style="font-family: Courier New;" type="text" maxlength="10" size="10" />
```